# Multiple azure websites on same application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a web app that I need to deploy on different websites.

Conditions:

1. The application code is identical across all websites;
2. The application is database driven;
3. Different websites have to connect to different databases;
4. Connection strings for databases are defined in web.config.

How can I make different websites use the same deployment of the application with different web.config to pull data from different databases?

Here is what my control panel looks like now:
[image]

These websites are all applications that I publish separately out of Visual Studio.

The end goal is this:
[image]

I found this article: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/
It talks briefly about this in “Run the Same Project in Two Sites in the Web Role”

But it seems like this is supposed to be for a local setup and does not discuss how I can get this on the remote Azure instance.

Comment: the blog post you refer talks about very other service of Azure Cloud - namely Web Role Cloud Service. It is not Web Sites. What I don't understand is, why you have different Visual Studio projects when all the web sites / Apps have identical code, only web.config changes ... If you have different repositories, then your requirement is walk in the park to implement. In any way you have to have a separate Azure Web Site for each configuration and subdomain. The question is how to centralize management and deployment. Last question - do you plan to have more than 3 such "sites" or no ?

Comment: Right now I only have deployments that run different builds.

Now, I do have ONE project in VS that I can publish to any one of multiple domains (and I publish different branches of it in different domains), but I will need to deploy the same version on different websites.

Why would I deploy multiple copies of the same build of the same project: because I do not know how to share one project between different websites and have them all connect to different databases.

I plan on having at least a dozen different sites running off of different databases.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Here's how my publish screen looks like to give an idea:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRO3Q.jpg
Quick publish into different websites with different profiles in one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty straight forward. Not sure what exactly your issue is.

You can easily map (Deploy from source control) multiple Azure Web Sites to same source code repository. Then, if you are using VSO (Visual Studio Online), the linking will create a new CI build definition for each site. Then you only have to edit the Build Configuration to include the appropriate configuration settings for each environment.

If you are using other source control, you can still customize how the continuous deployment works. All the settings are configurable via a special `.dpeloyment` file. You can read more about [these configurable settings here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings). Most important part:

> SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:Configuration=Debug;PublishProfile=MyChainedTransform

You can change build configuration to match that of the target site.

Now, how to make this independently of the source control. Nice Kudu Gurus have thought about that, too. You can tweak these settings via [Application Setting for the web site itself](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments) (check section `Using App Settings instead of .deployment file`:

> Instead, you can use App Settings to set the same values that are supported 
>   in the .deployment file. The steps are:
>
> Go to the Configure tab for you site in the Azure portal
>
> Add an App Setting called `Project`, and set its value to something like
>   `WebProject/WebProject.csproj`
>
> Then in your other web site you can set Project to point to a different `.csproj` file.

So you add a new entry with key `SCM_BUILD_ARGS` and value `-p:Configuration=<your_desired_configuration>` in the Site Application Settings and you should be ready to go.

Disclaimer: have not check the solutions, but there is no reason why either should not work.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. This has led me to a large number of articles and set me on what I feel is the right track. My issue is that I know nothing about automatic online builds and I am not aware of linking an azure website to a VSO project.

As I understand it for a website to automatically grab a project from a VSO repository, I need to set up a build and run the build process (by trigger or queue)? When I have multiple builds defined (dev, release, test), can I tell the website to grab a specific build? How can I promote specific changesets to a build?

Comment: @astaykov I know this is an old post, but could you show any solution or documentation that helped you resolve this? I'm looking to deploy multiple webapps that use the same repository in VS. The difference being web.config. Right now they are manually editing web.config between publishing to different web apps.